# Getting a php session variable into js console

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a variable that is stored into my php session and I want to get it in the chrome console. Here is the code I have for the moment :

```
var gotV = <?php echo json_encode($access_token); ?>;
```

This code won't work in the chrome console, so it's a bit annoying. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you have stored the value of php variable in `session` and you want to print that in `console`.
Make sure you save the file as **.php** extension.

```
<?php
  // Print in console from PHP to JS
  session_start();
  $god = 'hare krishna';
  //now save $god to php-session
  $access_token = $_SESSION['god'] = $god;
  // making JS script
  $con = '<script>';
  $con .='console.log("from PHP :'. $access_token .'")';
  $con .= '</script>';
  // printing to JS-console
  echo $con;
?>


<script>
  // Print in console from JS to PHP
  let gotV = 'from js : ' + <?php echo json_encode($access_token); ?>;
  console.log(gotV);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

surely because you forgot to place quotes around php tags !

`var gotV = "<?php echo json_encode($access_token); ?>";`

Anyway, try to display source code of page, you'll see how it's outputted currently

Comment: if you want it in the console, you have to ouptut it to the console with `console.log(gotV)`...

Comment: Still not. Just returns me the string again, and not the defined variable.

Comment: maybe you should explain better what you are up to. What is exactly "the string again" ? and what do you expect as the "defined variable".

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
session_start();
$session_var = isset($_SESSION['id'] ? $_SESSION['id'] : '';
?>

<html>
<head>
<script>
var my_var = '<?php echo $session_var ?>';
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining what you did to fix the problem.